# Confusion about the RWT and LTO timeout of NFC P2P

Tags: timeout, nfc, rfid, nfc-p2p

I am a little bit confused about the interaction of the timeouts of ISO18092 (RWT = Response Waiting Time) and LLCP (LTO = Link Timeout).

I have several NFC phones (e.g. Samsung Nexus S or Samsung Galaxy S3) that return a WT value of 14 within the ATR_RES, although the LLCP specifies a WT of less than or equal to 8.
The first question is how the initiator should behave when the signaled WT (14) is greater than the maximum specified WT (8)? Should simply a WT = 8 be assumed?

If the WT = 14 is correct, this results in a RWT of 4949 ms. But these targets signal also a LTO of 1500 ms, which should be sufficiently larger than RWT to allow one or more error recovery cycles (according to the LLCP specification). How should the initiator handle this case? Did anyone have the same problems?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply non-compliant behaviour. But for LLCP communication the Link Timeout LTO determines when the game is over - if the NFC-DEP Response Waiting Time RWT is not smaller than LTO there is unfortunately no chance for error recovery of lost NFC-DEP packets.